# Jhipster Create or Edit a Entity Not Found Error

Tags: entity, jhipster

This is my first StackOverflow questions and I'm pretty new to Jhipster so hopefully this makes sense. I started a Jhipster project and used JDL studio to create some entities.

When I try to make create a new entity (like Blog) I just get two red boxes that say "**Not Found.**"

What should I do in order to create entities? I've attached a screenshot below.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Blogtest error screenshot]

Comment: Did you restart your backend (mvn or gradle) after creating the entity?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for all of your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restart Graven or Maven wrapper after the entity has been created.

Comment: You are correct. Stackoverflow to the rescue learning a new framework. So far jhipster looks pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing, you should first check the logs and see what error code is written. If it is error code 500, it means the server is not online, or there is an error with the back end server logic or the database itself.
In the former case you might need to run on the back end server a liquibase migration command e.g.

```
mvn clean compile liquibase:diff && mvn liquibase:update
```

This is because table might not have been created in the database, especially if you run maven with the no-liquibase profile selected (easy to accidentally select when running from the IDE)

If it is error code 401, then it means that you have authorization issues, which might be resolved by logging in and logging out, or refreshing the page entirely (in which case the angular http-interceptors will now log you out).

There are many other error codes you can see right there on the browser and that gives you a head start in resolving the problem.

To see these logs all you need to do on your browser is crtl + shift + i (am assuming you are using chrome) and navigate to the console. Pick the messages highlighted with red background.

If you can't access logs, you will be programming by brute force. It works too, but from my experience, I log as much as possible, and read as many logs as I can especially when unexpected behaviors occur. Brute force programming works, but it's much harder.